# how to align fieldset next to each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my attempt to align them that I have been trying, I have searched StackOverflow as well but still unable to. I have to align them exactly like in the picture. When I do it, the radio button and text flow somewhere else. Please help, I'm a beginner please be kind!

```css
#text {
         font-family: sans-serif;
         font-size: 1em;
         color: #000;
         text-decoration: none;
       }
       #f1 {
        width: 68px;
        display: inline-block;
       }

       #f2 {
        width: 229px;
        left: 151px;
        float: right;
        top: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
       }

       input {
        margin: 4px;
       }

       label {

       }
```

```html
<div style="width:900px; height:4px">
            <fieldset id="f1">
                <legend>Font Size</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-1" value=".5em">
                <label for="size-1">.5em</label>
                <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-2" value="1em" checked>
                <label for="size-2">1em</label>
                <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-3" value="2em">
                <label for="size-3">2em</label>
                <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-4" value="3em">
                <label for="size-4">3em</label>
                </fieldset>
        </div> 

        <div style="width:26%; top:0px;float:left;">
            <fieldset id="f2">
            <legend>Other Font Features</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="features" id="italic" value="italic">
            <label for="italic">Italic</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="features" id="underline" value="underline">
            <label for="underline">Underline</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="features" id="small-caps" value="small-caps">
            <label for="small-caps">Small-caps</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
     <fieldset id="f3">
       <legend>Font Color</legend>
       <input type="radio" name="font-color" id="color-1" value="red">
       <label for="color-1">Red</label>
       <input type="radio" name="font-color" id="color-2" value="green">
       <label for="color-2">Green</label>
       <input type="radio" name="font-color" id="color-3" value="blue">
       <label for="color-3">Blue</label>
       <input type="radio" name="font-color" id="color-4" value="pink">
       <label for="color-4">Pink</label>
     </fieldset>

     <div id="text">
       THE ANALYTICAL ENGINE HAS NO PRETENSIONS WHATEVER TO ORIGINATE ANYTHING. IT CAN DO WHATEVER WE KNOW HOW TO ORDER IT TO PERFORM. ADA LoVELACE, THE WORLD'S FIRST COMPUTER PROGRAMMER
     </div>

     <button type="button" id="done">Done</button>
```

This is how it should look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8lvN.png)

Comment: Try flexbox to horizontally align block level element next to each other.

Comment: Remember one thing that try to avoid INLINE-STYLE

Comment: @g78 CSS has advantages over inline-style. There are plenty of reasons to use it though: Email-templates, specificity weight, editability on certain website hosters...

Comment: @tacoshy I understand what you are trying to say, but I wanted to convey is that 'Dont implement inline-styles as shown in the Answer by Eronred'. Also I didn't ask him to completely avoid inline-style

Answer (score 0):

I made it for you as inline-style as you see. Just add Other Font Features and Font Color. Also, it would be better to use flex, not float. Plus, add your input and label inside a div to make them centered. Just copy that code in your VSC and see the result.

```
<div style="display:flex; align-items:flex-start; flex-direction: column;">


        <h1>Make your font selections and click Done</h1>
        
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;" class="fieldset-wrapper">
            <div>
                <fieldset style="display: flex; align-items:center; flex-direction: column; " id="f1">
                    <legend>Font Size</legend>
                    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-1" value=".5em">
                        <label for="size-1">.5em</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-2" value="1em" checked>
                        <label for="size-2">1em</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-3" value="2em">
                        <label for="size-3">2em</label>
                    </div>

                    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-4" value="3em">
                        <label for="size-4">3em</label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div>
                <fieldset style="display: flex; align-items:center; flex-direction: column; " id="f1">
                    <legend>Font Size</legend>
                    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-1" value=".5em">
                        <label for="size-1">.5em</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-2" value="1em" checked>
                        <label for="size-2">1em</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-3" value="2em">
                        <label for="size-3">2em</label>
                    </div>

                    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-4" value="3em">
                        <label for="size-4">3em</label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div>
                <fieldset style="display: flex; align-items:center; flex-direction: column; " id="f1">
                    <legend>Font Size</legend>
                    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-1" value=".5em">
                        <label for="size-1">.5em</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-2" value="1em" checked>
                        <label for="size-2">1em</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-3" value="2em">
                        <label for="size-3">2em</label>
                    </div>

                    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="font-size" id="size-4" value="3em">
                        <label for="size-4">3em</label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button style="margin-top:12px;" type="button" id="done">Done</button>

        <div style="margin-top:12px; max-width: 800px; text-decoration:underline; color:red;" id="text">
            THE ANALYTICAL ENGINE HAS NO PRETENSIONS WHATEVER TO ORIGINATE ANYTHING. IT CAN DO WHATEVER WE KNOW HOW TO
            ORDER
            IT TO PERFORM. ADA LoVELACE, THE WORLD'S FIRST COMPUTER PROGRAMMER
        </div>
    </div>
```